# why opendkim says it isn't running when it is

Tags: opendkim

I installed postfix in a docker container, and installed opendkim there as well.

Every time I run a `service opendkim status`, it gives me `opendkim is not running`. I tried `sysctl status opendkim`, and got this:

```
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/status: No such file or directory
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/opendkim: No such file or directory
```

However, doing `ps -aux | grep opendkim` shows me that it is indeed running. I tested postfix and the mails are indeed being signed. I just don't know why it isn't showing as a running daemon.

Answer (score 1):

You confused `sysctl` with `systemctl`, sysctl sets kernel variables and correctly claims that there are no variables called status and opendkim.

If the command `systemctl status opendkim` also says that it's not running, opendkim might have been started with a different mechanism (and not with systemd)

Comment: Issue is `system opendkim status` says `opendkim` is not running, `sysctl`/`systemctl` is a red herring.